# Order post grid by custom (acf) field - still not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to order (sort) my posts in elementor post grid by an (acf) custom field "fakedatum" (see img sjh-1.jpg).
I put some code in 'code snipped pro' (not in 'functions.php'):

```
add_action( 'elementor/post/actsort', function( $query ) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', 'activiteiten' );
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'fakedatum' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value meta_value_num' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
});
```

But the post are not ordered by 'fakedatum'. I didn't figure out what I did wrong.
Any suggestions? snippits?
Help!

Comment: That looks specific to both elementor and ACF. You’d be best asking them for support.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the key is `fakedatum` and not something like `_fakedatum`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to sort by an acf field by using

```
    add_action( 'elementor/query/actsort', function( $query ) {
        
      $query->set( 'meta_key', 'fakedatum' );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
      $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    
    })
```

Add `actsort` as query ID in the post loop. In other words add it to the loop by ID.